# Fill missing beta dates in the API

Tags: feature-request, beta-phase, api

When putting together a [table with launch dates of SE sites](http://dropproxy.com/f/A62), I noticed that API does not return beta  dates for certain sites: namely, those that did not go through Area 51.

```
Site Name             Private Beta      Public Beta           Launch
Stack Overflow             ?                 ?              2008-09-14
Server Fault               ?                 ?              2009-05-25
Super User                 ?                 ?              2009-08-17
Meta Stack Exchange        ?                 ?              2009-06-27
Stack Apps                 ?                 ?              2010-05-19
Ask Patents                ?                 ?              2012-09-19
MathOverflow               ?                 ?              2009-09-28
Sound Design               ?                 ?              2010-11-09
CS50                       ?                 ?  
edx-cs169-1x               ?                 ? 
スタック・オーバーフロー        ?                 ?
```

Some of these sites   had a beta period: [Stack Overflow](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2008/07/stack-overflow-private-beta-begins/),  [Server Fault](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/04/server-fault-private-beta-begins/), [Super User](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/07/super-user-semi-private-beta-begins/), and ja.SO (which is in public beta now). But the dates of these important site events are now found only in scattered blog posts, and the transition from private to public beta (if any) seems near impossible to track down.

I suggest backfilling the beta dates of SO|F|U and ja.SO, so that the API `/sites/` method returns them along with the rest.

Comment: What about the ones that *didn't* have beta phases? Meta Stack Exchange (formerly Meta Stack Overflow) never did. I'm pretty sure Stack Apps never did either. Tbh I'm not sure what they consider Ask Patents to be. I doubt they will ever change the beta-like privileges for that site.

Comment: I'm okay with not having beta dates for sites that were never in beta... I listed them in the table for completeness, and also because some are weird edge cases like Patents and the edX sites.